# Scrolling tableView section footer and header

Tags: ios, header, tableview, footer

I have view, which is set in fund viewForHeader/footerInSection...
I want it to appear only after scrolling to the end/top of the section.
Currently it is over my cell's.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just change table style to be Grouped
[image]